# IF command for 2 date columns in 2 different tables

Tags: date, if-statement

I want to compare 2 date columns in 2 different tables using the IF command but it keeps saying the syntax is wrong.
What is the correct command for me to use in this scenario?

I created a relationship between the two tables and used the command:

```
IF(RELATED('POHDPM (2)[OrderDate].[Date])>'JCCM'[TakeOffDeadline],"Out Of Phase","In Phase")
```

I have 2 columns POHDPM (2)[OrderDate] and JCMM[TakeOffDeadline], I want to show the order dates that have exceeded the Take Off Deadline. These columns are in 2 different tables.

Comment: What language are you writing this in?

Comment: Please provide some context to your question and remember that's your interest to be clear if you want to get any feedback. Cya

Comment: The command is in Dax